# How to render or hide a jsf subview based on a method call (which returns boolean)?

Tags: java, jsf

I have a context loader class which loads an XML file with info on which components to show or hide on a page. On the JSP pages, within  the 'rendered' attribute for a subView,, I would like to make a call to 
ContextLoader.displayPageComponent(String pageId, String componentId) which returns a boolean. Does this work in JSF? If not, is there another way to achieve the same?

Comment: Which version of JSF are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap it in an EL function. How to do it exactly depends on the view technology in question. You can find a JSP-targeted example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609969/how-can-i-parse-a-url-using-jsp-jstl/2611912#2611912) and a Facelets-targeted example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378826/facelets-and-jstl-converting-a-date-to-a-string-for-use-in-a-field/2381443#2381443).

Answer (score 1):

The most direct way to do this would be have a backing bean with a method like this...

```
public boolean isRenderSubview1Comp1() {
   return ContextLoader.displayPageComponent("subview1", "comp1");
}
```

with

`<h:outputText value="foo" rendered="#{MyBean.rednerSubview1Comp1}"/>`

Comment: I am trying to externalize the page component configuration. So I don't want to go this route.